# How to Render PDF in Angular 5?

Tags: angular

I have server code (rest service) in java:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/Trip/PDF/{tripId}")
    @Produces("application/pdf")
    public javax.ws.rs.core.Response getPdf(@PathParam("tripId") Integer tripId) throws Exception {
...

byte[] pdf = null;  
...
javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ok((Object) pdf);
        responseBuilder.type("application/pdf");
        responseBuilder.header("Content-Disposition", "filename=tripPdf.pdf");
        return responseBuilder.build();
```

Using the the url directly in the browser I am able to see the generated PDF but
when trying to call the url from angular I get nothing (the java code run).

The call from UI:

```
<a (click)="generateTripPdf(data.trip.id)" href="#" target="_blank">
```

The service call (the tripId is available):

```
 generateTripPdf(tripId) {
       this.documentService.getTripPdf(tripId);
      }
```

The service:

```
const httpOptionsPdf = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Accept': 'application/pdf', 'Content-Type': 'application/pdf' })
};

@Injectable()
export class DocumentService {
  ...
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
...
  public getTripPdf(tripId) { 
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.baseUrl}/Doc/Trip/PDF/${tripId}`, httpOptionsPdf);
  }
```

Any idea how to get it working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.In your component,

```
constructor() {
  this.baseUrl = 'your-url';
  this.pdfUrl = `${this.baseUrl}/Doc/Trip/PDF/${tripId}`;
}
```

And in your template.

```
  <a [href]="pdfUrl" target="_blank">Download PDF.</a> <br>
```

Hope this helps.